# Why terraform thinks that I changed many atttributes from "" to null?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I just executed `terraform plan` and it report a lots of spurious changes. It reports that it needs to recreate a lot of resource because some attributes that were `""`(empty string) are not `null`.

For example it think that I changed this route in

```
route            = [
      - {
          - cidr_block                = "0.0.0.0/0"
          - egress_only_gateway_id    = ""
          - gateway_id                = "igw-xxxx"
          - instance_id               = ""
          - ipv6_cidr_block           = ""
          - nat_gateway_id            = ""
          - network_interface_id      = ""
          - transit_gateway_id        = ""
          - vpc_peering_connection_id = ""
        },
      + {
          + cidr_block                = "0.0.0.0/0"
          + egress_only_gateway_id    = null
          + gateway_id                = "igw-xxxx"
          + instance_id               = null
          + ipv6_cidr_block           = null
          + nat_gateway_id            = null
          + network_interface_id      = null
          + transit_gateway_id        = null
          + vpc_peering_connection_id = null
        },
```

As far as I can tell, there is no actual change (in the terraform configuration) so I suspect
this must be some discrepancy betweent the stores state and how terraform computes the "desired" state.

What is causing this? Is this a change between terraform 0.13.1 and 0.13.5?

Comment: Rather than Terraform upgrade, I *guess* it might rather be the `terraform-provider-aws` upgrade which might have caused this. Although I haven't seen it myself.

Comment: Can you share a wider amount of the plan to provide context please? Right now it's hard to see if this is just because something else is changing and it's just showing a slightly wider diff than you might be used to.

Comment: I repro'd this, and can verify it was introduced when I upgraded some TF from 0.11.14 to 0.12.28.

I only see the bug when I'm changing another route in the same table (using in-line routes).

You can work around it by explicitly defining the empty fields.  I'll add that in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. This reply nailed the workaround: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/terraform-wants-to-replace-many-resources-because-it-detects-that-null/17845/2

I'm not sure when or how this is bug was introduced in the AWS provider, but it cropped up for me after upgrading from 0.11.14 to 0.12.28.

If you explicitly define all of these null values, Terraform stops seeing this as a change.

```
   route {
-    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
-    gateway_id = "igw-ID"
+    cidr_block                = "0.0.0.0/0"
+    gateway_id                = "igw-ID"
+    egress_only_gateway_id    = ""
+    instance_id               = ""
+    ipv6_cidr_block           = ""
+    nat_gateway_id            = ""
+    network_interface_id      = ""
+    transit_gateway_id        = ""
+    vpc_peering_connection_id = ""
```

Changes my plan from destroying and recreating all of the routes to just adding a new route (anonymized values):

```
  # aws_route_table.main-vpc-ID will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_route_table" "main-vpc-ID" {
        id               = "rtb-ID"
        owner_id         = "accountid"
        propagating_vgws = []
      ~ route            = [
            {
                cidr_block                = "0.0.0.0/0"
                egress_only_gateway_id    = ""
                gateway_id                = "igw-ID"
                instance_id               = ""
                ipv6_cidr_block           = ""
                nat_gateway_id            = ""
                network_interface_id      = ""
                transit_gateway_id        = ""
                vpc_peering_connection_id = ""
            },
          + {
              + cidr_block                = "10.100.2.0/24"
```